# How google facets visualization tool can be embed into web page

Tags: javascript, html, jupyter-notebook, facet, quickdraw

I'm referring to the source project from [facets](https://github.com/PAIR-code/facets)

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10

As per the instructions, I've installed bazel build and run the facets in my local by referring quick demo for [facets demo](https://pair-code.github.io/facets/) using jupyter notebook.

Visualizations are shown [here](https://pair-code.github.io/facets/quickdraw.html)

I want the visualization would be embedded on a web page

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this part of their README: https://github.com/PAIR-code/facets/blob/master/facets_dive/README.md#embedding-dive-in-your-page

> The project is built with Bazel. Make sure you have installed Bazel and run the Bazel BUILD files prior to proceeding. Provided you've loaded the  Polymer element, you can insert an instance into your page like so.

```
<facets-dive></facets-dive>
```

> To set the data, you'll need to add a little JavaScript. In your code, first get a reference to this DOM element, then assign your array of objects to the data attribute.

```
const vis = document.querySelector('facets-dive');
vis.data = [ ... your data ... ];
```

Comment: Got the result. In Github build failure of facets were fixed April 12th. Refer https://github.com/PAIR-code/facets/issues/121